# Conditionally formatting overlapping records

Tags: c#, excel, formatting, interop, conditional-statements

I have this piece of code. I want to color the background with green in the rows that begin with `Sat` or `Sun`. I also want to color with red font the cells that are smaller than a specific value.

```
            // Color the row when the day is Saturday or Sunday
            var rang2 = ws.Range["$A$5:$M35"];
            Excel.FormatCondition condition2 = (Excel.FormatCondition)rang2.FormatConditions.Add(
             Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression,
             Type.Missing, "=OR(TEXT($A1,\"ddd\")=\"Sun\",TEXT($A1,\"ddd\")=\"Sat\")",  Type.Missing, Type.Missing,Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

           // Color with red
            var rang = ws.Range["$K$5:$L35"];
            Excel.FormatCondition condition = (Excel.FormatCondition)rang.FormatConditions.Add(
         Excel.XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
         Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, "=$L$5", Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
         Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
condition2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50; condition2.Font.ColorIndex = 1; // Green Background and Black font
condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 0; condition.Font.ColorIndex = 3; // White Background and Red font
```

The problem is that the two conditional formats are overlapping each other. I tried changing the order of the two conditional formats, but still I cannot make it work.

With this setup, the first rule will contain also the red font, and the second rule contains only the white background and black text (instead of red text).

Comment: Is it a requirement to use the conditional formatting? It would have been a lot easier to just write out the logic in C#

Comment: I am trying to save into an Excel file. The final file will be send to someone, so I need the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

It should and it does work for me if you change the order. You need to have xlCellValue (s) first, xlExpression later. ie: This code works as expected for me:

```
void Main()
{
  var tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
  new SqlDataAdapter(@"
  WITH  tally ( OrderNo, UniqueId, RandNumber )
        AS (
             SELECT TOP 50000
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY t1.object_id ), 
                    NEWID(),
                    CAST(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(4)) AS INT) AS DECIMAL) / 1000
             FROM   master.sys.all_columns t1
             CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns t2
           )
  SELECT  OrderNo, 
    DATEADD(DAY, -OrderNo, GETDATE()) as OrnekDate, 
    UniqueId, RandNumber, 
    abs(RandNumber)%100 / 100 as pct
  FROM [tally];", @"server=.\SQLExpress;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=yes;").Fill(tbl);

  object[,] arr = new object[tbl.Rows.Count + 1, tbl.Columns.Count];
  for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Columns.Count; i++)
  {
    arr[0, i] = tbl.Columns[i].Caption;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < tbl.Rows.Count; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < tbl.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
      arr[i + 1, j] = tbl.Rows[i][j].ToString();
    }
  }

  // Excel dosya yarat ve arrayi koy
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xl = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  var workbook = xl.Workbooks.Add();
  xl.Visible = true;

 Worksheet sht = ((Worksheet)workbook.ActiveSheet);
 Range target = (Range)sht.Range[ (Range)sht.Cells[1,1], (Range)sht.Cells[arr.GetUpperBound(0)+1,arr.GetUpperBound(1)+1] ];
 target.Value = arr;
 ((Range)sht.Range["D:D"]).NumberFormat = "$#,##0.0000";
 ((Range)sht.Range["E:E"]).NumberFormat = "0.00%";

  // Color with red
  var rang = sht.Range["$D$5:$D35"];
  FormatCondition condition = (FormatCondition)rang
  .FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
  XlFormatConditionOperator.xlLess, "0");


  // Color the row when the day is Saturday or Sunday
  var rang2 = sht.Range["$A$5:$M35"];
  FormatCondition condition2 = (FormatCondition)rang2
    .FormatConditions.Add(XlFormatConditionType.xlExpression, Type.Missing, 
      @"=OR(TEXT($A1,""ddd"")=""Sun"",TEXT($A1,""ddd"")=""Sat"")");

  condition2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50; 
  condition2.Font.ColorIndex = 1; // Green Background and Black font
  condition.Interior.ColorIndex = 0; 
  condition.Font.ColorIndex = 3; // White Background and Red font

}
```